# javascript - script is not working

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm trying to build "hit the image" game where few images are displayed on page while "covered" and one image (which image is changing) is "open".
My idea was to start a while loop on user choice that will create a random id (each card has an id) and send it to another function. That part works fine I think.
Function number 2 should "flip" the cards for 1 second and then cover them again. 
In the console I can see that the "flip" class is being added but not removed, but on the page all of the cards are "covered".
I think the problem is that the first function is sending random numbers too fast while the flip function has a timeout set. Can anyone confirm it?
Any ideas on how to solve?

The code is:
Please don't mind the ugly button

```js
var currentCard;
var audioWin = new Audio('sound/win.mp3');
var idNum="a"


//gets string id and removes "flipped" class from it
function flip(idNum){
  console.log("in flip");
  currentCard=document.getElementById(idNum);
  currentCard.classList.add('flipped');

  setTimeout(function () {
    currentCard.classList.remove('flipped');
  }, 1000)


}
//plays sounds if users hits img while card is "open"
function ifClicked(currentCard){
  if(currentCard.classList.contains('flipped')){
    audioWin.play();
  }
  else{
    //put another short sound
  }
  
}
//creates random nums in range 1-4
function randCard(){
  while(true){
    var secretNum=Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1);
    idNum=secretNum.toString();
    console.log(idNum);
    flip(idNum);
    //document.getElementById(idNum);
  }
  
  
}
```

```css
.card{
    background-color: pink;
    height: 165px;
    width: 165px;    
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}
.card img {
    position: absolute;
}

.flipped .back {
    display: none;
}

.button{
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="t.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id ="1" class="card" onclick="ifClicked(this);">
    <img src="img/cards/1.png">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">
  </div>
  <div id="2"class="card" onclick="ifClicked(this);">
    <img src="img/cards/2.png">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">
  </div>
  <div id="3" class="card"  onclick="ifClicked(this);">
    <img src="img/cards/3.png">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">
  </div>
  <div id="4" class="card"  onclick="ifClicked(this);">
    <img src="img/cards/4.png">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">
  </div>
</div>    
<div class="button" onclick="randCard();">here</div>
</body>
<script src="j.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: First and foremost, the `while(true){...}` is incorrect.  That will block everything and make your page unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, I think you are on to it, I would remove the loop from this function:

```
function randCard(){
    var secretNum=Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1);
    idNum=secretNum.toString();
    console.log(idNum);
    flip(idNum);
  }
```

Then call randCard() again once the shown card times out and is turned back over:

```
function flip(idNum){
  console.log("in flip");
  currentCard=document.getElementById(idNum);
  currentCard.classList.add('flipped');

  setTimeout(function () {
    currentCard.classList.remove('flipped');
    randCard();
  }, 1000)


}
```

And then once the DOM loads, call randCard() to start the cycle:

```
//PLace this right after your global variable declarations
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    //Initial call of randCard()
    randCard();
}
```